# Ubuntu 16.04 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, usb, partitioning

I have only Ubuntu on my PC and, after 2 years, I have to return to Windows. I have three question.

1. How do I create a bootable USB with Windows? To create the USB with Ubuntu I've always used the default "disk utility" of Ubuntu. Can I do the same thing for Windows? And which set up should I select (BIOS/EUFI)? Here is the status of my partitions:

[image: here]

2. Should I delete all the partitions?
3. After creating the USB, is the installation process equal to that of Ubuntu?

Answer (score -2):

I recommend the [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool)

Will create a bootable USB for versions of Windows 7 onwards. caveat - windows only.

If using Linux/OSX/Windows - [Etcher](https://etcher.io/)

As to your other issues - UEFI is recommended.

Unless you are trying to do a dual-boot installation, wipe all partitions, all data will be lost of course.